# Ubuntu 14.10 LSI 9240-8i driver installation

Tags: drivers, 14.10, raid

I'm quite new to Linux and just got my LSI 9240-8i
I'm running ubuntu on a normal SSD on the Mobo sata port.

i've downloaded the drivers for ubuntu from here: http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-con....aspx#tab/tab4
they are however for 10.04 and 10.10, and i have no idea what to do with the provided files in the ZIP.

any guidelines? I've never installed drivers for anything on Ubuntu (or any other linux).

when I run the lspci command i can find my LSI Logic card.

edit:
Ok, I've found the .deb file in their Latest Linux Drivers pack. but they are only for 14.04 whilst im running .10
i've installed them but I still don't see any drives.

edit2:

```
stefan@server:~/Desktop/ubuntu/rpms-1$ sudo dpkg -i megaraid_sas_06.705.06.00-1-ubuntu14.04_x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 217629 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack megaraid_sas_06.705.06.00-1-ubuntu14.04_x86_64.deb ...
pre 06.705.06.00
Unpacking megaraid-sas (06.705.06.00-1) over (06.705.06.00-1) ...
postun 06.705.06.00
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_5POLxa/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_5POLxa/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Working files in /tmp/mkinitramfs_5POLxa, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_7c9eul and overlay in /tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_5EbYPL
Working files in /tmp/mkinitramfs_Sv4Sv7, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_pXqJ91 and overlay in /tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_ywjkGc
Working files in /tmp/mkinitramfs_RINtod, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_YkJKRv and overlay in /tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_eaTRV2
Uninstall Done.
Setting up megaraid-sas (06.705.06.00-1) ...
post 06.705.06.00
post Install Done.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it fixed by installing Ubuntu 14.04.1. worked out of the box.

Comment: Sorry to bump a really old post but have you tried with 15.04 or 14.10 since? Looking to replace my broken card that has severe compatibility issues with this one but I need to know if it will be compatible without issues.

Comment: @electrometro I'm still using 14.04. 15.04 might work, just give it a go. also have a look on their website for drivers.